# Is it possible for my Sony Xperia Neo L to take other earphones besides SONY earphones

Tags: audio, sony-xperia-neo-l, earphone

My Sony earphones are damaged, I've got other earphones (non-SONY) but are not accepted by the phone. Is there a way to make them work ??

Comment: What do you mean by "not accepted"?

Answer (score 1):

There are different standards for headset plugs, and Sony has started using the CTIA layout for it's smartphones since 2012. I couldn't find the official documentation on the differences, but it's pretty well explained [here](http://www.martzell.de/2012/12/pin-belegung-headset-iphone-omtp-ctia.html) (In german, but the pictures speak for themselves).

The gist is, on regular headsets the order of the pins is ground-mic-right-left, but on CTIA it's mic-ground-right-left.

To get regular headsets working, you'll have to use an adapter, but if I'm understanding this correctly, headphones (that is, without a microphone) should work normally.

Answer (score -1):

You can try Nokia's headphones. I think they will work with them.